# SQL Operation order for 'AFTER' and 'COMMENT'

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

Hello I need to edit a database to add new columns. But I encountered a little problem, because I need to add comments to these new columns and I also need to add them after a certain column in the exist table.

Is this the correct syntax? :

```
ALTER TABLE `table`
ADD COLUMN `new` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '...' AFTER `secondlastcolumn`;
```

Or would this be correct? :

```
ALTER TABLE `table`
ADD COLUMN `new` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' AFTER `secondlastcolumn` COMMENT '...';
```

Or is there another way of doing this?

I couldn't find a answer with an ***ADD COLUMN***, only for modifying columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ALTER TABLE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) defines `ADD COLUMN` definition as

> ADD [COLUMN] *col_name column_definition* [FIRST | AFTER *col_name*]

[CREATE TABLE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html) defines `COMMENT` is a part of *column_definition*.

So `COMMENT` then `AFTER`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reaction, I didn't fully understand how to read that part of the documentation :o, but I now somewhat see how to.